# WPA Enterprise (PEAP - MSCHAPv2) on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, wpa-supplicant, wpa2

As many of us know, wpa_supplicant has a bug that afflicts the wpa-enterprise (PEAP - MSCHAPv2) to disconnect frequently.

In my experience the wifi went down and retried to reconnect randomly making me very crazy because I couldn't go online !
I didn't find out if it depend of the wifi driver (I have a ALFA AWUS 1900 with a rtl8814au chipset) or directly from the wpa_supplicant bug.

Anyway, I tried many distro like debian, fedora and so on... But in the last days I tried Ubuntu 14.04.6 on VirtualBox linked directly the usb wifi adapter, and after installed the driver and set up the network I saw the network worked very well without the frequent disconnections. 
So today I installed the wpa_supplicant package version from Ubuntu trusty (14.04) on my Ubuntu 18.04 and it seems it works as expected.
So I need your help to confirm my suppositions and maybe bring the all community to fix that strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To try what I did first you need to add the Trusty repository on your machine. To do that you can simply copy and past these lines (that I taken directly from Ubuntu 14.04.6) to a new file on /etc/apt/source.list.d/trusty.list:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

then update apt

```
sudo apt update
```

Now you are able to downgrade the wpa_supplicant package

```
sudo apt install --allow-downgrades wpasupplicant=2.1-0ubuntu1.7
```

mark as hold the package to prevent it to upgrade

```
sudo apt-mark hold wpasupplicant
```

now you can reboot and try if your network works !

Please let me know if your network problems disappear or are still there !